# Segmented bones twist in object mode

Tags: rigging, armature

I am new to blender and attempting to rig up a test model, but while the armature looks fine in Edit Mode, it seems to twist the moment I enter Object Mode.

[image: Armature in Edit Mode]

[image: Armature in Object Mode]

I thought at first, that it was because I had too many segments, but it happens with even just two segments.

Can anybody alert me as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In the Armature Properties Panel, set the skeletal pose to "reset position" to see if the problem is the rig or the pose. this will help isolate the problem.

Comment: @JohnsonMartin No change when I do that.